# Why can I not use a duplicate DC computer name for a subdomain as a parent domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

I am new to AD and Windows Server in general, but from what I've seen on youtube, companies can have something like this:

```
www.example.com
www.eng.example.com
```

I figured this meant that there is a web server in the example.com domain named www, and there is a different web server in the eng.example.com domain also named www. This would imply that you can use a duplicate computer name on a parent domain and its subdomain. When I try to do this in practice however, I get this error when trying to promote the second Windows Server 2012 machine to a DC:

```
A domain controller with the specified name already exists
```

Does this mean that in the above case, www does not refer to a specific machine, but rather the company uses DNS to alias www.example.com to say webserver1.example.com and www.eng.example.com to say webserver2.eng.example.com?

Comment: You are taking a shortcut here to the conclusion. The fact that these servers has same first part of the hostname doesn't mean it has to be that server's name, especially its AD name. It's just a DNS name pointing to that server.

Comment: What?  Why do you think the dns name has anything to do with the computer name?  Sure AD will have a DNS entry for a computer name, but you can easily create additional A records or CNAME records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then the answer is that yes, you would typically use DNS to "alias" different hostnames to the same computer, which might have a different name entirely.

To take you example - assuming it's two different web servers, you wouldn't need to give either of them the computer name `www`, even though that's the beginning of the URL users would use to access the sites. Assuming your AD domain is `example.com`, and you name your web servers `web01` and `web02`, their fully qualified names would be `web01.example.com.` and `web02.example.com.`.

One way of setting up your example could be:

- `www.example.com` is an alias (`CNAME`) in DNS for `web01.example.com`
- `www.eng.example.com` is an alias (`CNAME`) in DNS for `web02.example.com`

You might even have both sites hosted on the same server and use host headers to allow the HTTP server to serve a different site depending on the DNS name used to access the site. In that case DNS might look like this:

- `www.example.com` is an alias (`CNAME`) for `web01.example.com`
- `www.eng.example.com` is also an alias (`CNAME`) for `web01.example.com`

**EDIT**

As your question mentions AD, I've assumed your question relates to internal sites such as an intranet. Although I've used "example.com" in the example to keep things simple, in the real world you should typically be choosing a domain name for your internal DNS that won't conflict with an internet DNS domain. See [Microsoft's recommendations](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc726016%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: Your link to the Microsoft recommendations is pointing to an outdated page. These days you should take a domain which can exist in real life because very often (e.g. with Exchange servers) you need to be able to get valid certificates. Because of this is it now recommended to take something like e.g. ad.company.com See here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc726016%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks - hadn't noticed I'd linked to the 2003 version. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

What dbr wrote is valid for DNS but is not the real reason of the error message you get. Active Directory is a combination of several protocols ([LDAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol), [Kerberos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29), DNS, etc.) Before we had Active Directory we had "workgroups" and along with the it the protocols NetBIOS (actually [NBT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS_over_TCP/IP)) and WINS.

Withing LDAP you have now different domains as well. Microsoft simplified a lot of things by making the LDAP domain having the same name as the DNS domain name. But technically it doesn't have to be. The error message you got before is because of the LDAP domain and not because of the DNS domain. I recommend you to read [this page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770319%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) on Microsoft technet so you know the differences between a forest and a domain. You can have within a forest several domains and you can have within the different domains the same server names (although I would not recommend it.)

Comment: "You can have within a forest several domains and you can have within the different domains the same server names" - that is exactly what I did. Within a single forest, I had 2 domains: example.com and eng.example.com, and I tried to make a computer with the same name in those 2 different domains. It's not just not recommended - it doesn't appear to work at all. dbr confirmed my suspicions that even when DNS makes it look like maybe 2 machines have the same name, they don't. As far as I can tell, AD will not let you make 2 DCs with the same name in the same forest under any circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Old question with accepted answer but I ended up here by way of Google, so in addition to the answer of @dbr about CNAMEs:

Previous to Windows 2012 r2 the active directory could work with identical computernames, or SPNs really, in different domains of the same forest.

This was mostly true, but according to my poor memory there would occasionally be hickups with the AD refusing computers with identical names also prior to 2012 r2. Back then the AD would mostly just complain about identical SPNs in the logs. There are a number of different error messages related to this.

With Windows 2012 r2, Windows does a [default check for duplicate SPNs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/identity/ad-ds/manage/component-updates/spn-and-upn-uniqueness). This behaviour is possible to turn off with a [hotfix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3070083).

So even if the initial theoretical premise of AD in its first incarnation was to eliminate flat name databases, by basing the namespace on the hierarcical DNS name system, in practice Microsoft seems to have enforced name uniqueness within a forest.